# How to resolve a promise with an array of results from a different promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

I have a promise which is supposed to be resolved with an array. Each element of the resulting array is a result of a lengthy asynchronous operation itself, similar to this:

```
new Promise(resolve, reject) {
  const arr = [param1, param2, param3];
  const resultArr = [];

  async function foo(param) { return await ... };

  arr.forEach(param) {
    resultArr.push(foo(param));
  }
  
  resolve(resultArr);
}
```

The code above resolves with an array of unresolved promises, instead of actual values.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `Promise.all`. No need for `new Promise`.

Comment: Use Promise.all() to resolve when your array of promises all resolve